# how can I change the attribute value in supercalass from subclass permanently in python

Tags: python, oop

I want to change the value of attribute `pen_color` in `View` class **permanently** when I call `changeColor` method and the value still permenant unless I call the method again with another color,
when I call `changeColor` method the `pen_color` attribute still have the same value and I don't want such thing
Is there any way to do such thing or not ?

```
class View: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.pen_color = 'red'
    

class Button(View): 
    def __init__(self):
        pass
        
    def changeColor(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.pen_color = 'green'
```

Comment: Do you want to change the default value for the super class or only the value for one object?

Comment: @MichaelM. , for the superclass and for all objects created for it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move the declaration of pen color into a class attribute rather than an instance attribute and reference it as `View.pen_color`.

Having done that `View.pen_color` will be permanent and global, but can be shadowed by `self.pen_color` in either View or Button instances.

Comment: This is the best practice and a good answer, but the question is also asking if such a thing is possible (I have addressed the latter in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

This is not best practice, but if you really want then you can do it. To do this is to make a function to set the initial color in the superclass' `__init__()`, then change that function later on. Here's an example:

```
class View:
    def __init__(self):
        self.initColor()

    def initColor(self):
        self.pen_color = 'red'


class Button(View):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def changeColor(self, color):
        def newColor(self):
            self.pen_color = color
        View.initColor = newColor


btn = Button()
print(btn.pen_color) # returns 'red'
btn.changeColor('green')

btn2 = Button()
print(btn2.pen_color) # returns 'green'
```